# How dig my local server DNS directly

Tags: networking, bind, domain-name, dig

I created server DNS. I can dig my domain directly and I see that I have correct answer in my local network:
`dig example.com`

Why I can't get answer from my domain like `dig example.com @my_dns_server_name` ? Why connection is timed out?

This works:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 example.com
```

This works perfectly, globally too:

```
dig my_dns_server_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to make requests to your DNS server, you have to permit connections to the port for outside connections, so I would say this is a firewalling problem (either the router, or even the local machine or any other middle device can be blocking the device).

As you're digging from your local machine (`127.0.0.1`), no traffic is needed and you can query directly, that's why I assume this is a firewall problem.

DNS usually listens on a `53/UDP` port socket, so you would need to open that port for outside requests.

Comment: On my OpenWrt router, I opened port 53. I'm using raspberry3, so by default the firewall is off. You may be right that it is a router fault. I tried edit WAN and LAN interfaces with DNS options, but I'm not sure what will be correct. Thank You for help

Comment: And I assigned DNS forwardings to my local rpi IP and 8.8.8.8

Comment: Another possibilitty could be that your DNS server is configured to listen only on `localhost`, so any other IP than that could not be reaching the DNS server. A `netstat -atpun` should show what is it listening to.

Comment: Everything is OK now. I had the problem because of propagation delay